# Tensorflow 2 differentiate through optimization path?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, backpropagation

I am trying to compute "gradients through gradients" for a paper (MAML, by C.Finn et al.) in Tensorflow 2 with Keras backend. Thus, we start at some initial weights, compute K gradient update steps, and want to backpropagate through our initial weights. The code sample belows illustrates what I want to achieve, but unfortunately does not work.

```
optimizer = tf.keras.SGD()
initial_weights = model.trainable_variables

with tf.GradientTape() as mt:
    for gradient_steps in range(10):
        with tf.GradientTape() as t:
            loss = loss_function(y_train, model(x_train))
        grads = t.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    test_loss = loss_function(y_test, model(x_test))
mt.gradient(test_loss, initial_weights)
```

Does anyone know how to differentiate through the initialization? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to actually update the variables during your K initial passes, or you only would want to use the "provisional updates" during those K passes and only actually update the variables using the "gradients through gradients". In any case, I'm not sure there is a way to do this with common Keras code. It would be more straightforward if instead you had a `model` callable that received `x_train` _and_ the current parameter values. A normal Keras model will always use its `trainable_variables`, and gradients will not backpropagate through those.

Comment: If you want to assign a new value to a TensorFlow variable without breaking the gradient chain, you may use [`tf.grad_pass_through`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/grad_pass_through) - but that still will not allow you to do this with a "normal" Keras model I think.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you for your reply! I only want to use the "provisional updates" to compute the gradients through gradients, and use those to update the actual set of parameters. Thank you for your suggestion of using tf.grad_pass_through! I did not know this existed. I will try it out and hope it works. I will update this thread once I find out :)

Comment: @jdehesa Unfortunately it does not seem to work :s. It does not capture the dependencies